# C# Application settings

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a .NET 2.0 class library (web service) that I want to create settings for. However, when I try to create a settings file using the designer, I am unable to set the scope for the settings to User scope.

Does this have something to do with it being a web app? Is there any way I can store some settings easily? I need to store some values like an smtp host url.

Comment: does it need to be different for each user of the website? if not, just put it in AppSettings in the web.config

Comment: I dont know if I understood you. but have you tried with a web.config?

Comment: My guess is that these values need to be editable via some sort of configuration screen within the application.  Application scoped values are readonly.

Comment: @MatthewMartin no, it doesn't have to be different for each user of the website.

Comment: @MCSI how do I do it with a web.config?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, I was planning to make the setting editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what [ASP.NET Profiles](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx) was meant to address. You can still use the Profile object as long as you don't mind aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" (if you are doing WCF). I think if you're doing asmx web services, then Profile should be available.

Comment: Yes I am using asmx web services. I will try to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Web Applications don't allow for settings to be at the User scope.

A quick and dirty workaround I have used in some situations is to keep settings in a Dictionary and serialize / deserialize it to disk.

You could wrap the dictionary in a class to get strongly typed properties for your settings.  Add .save and .load methods and it will pretty much emulate the settings class you know and love.